# How to send username/password to htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

There is a way to send username and password to directories protected by .htaccess/htpasswd, using php? Rather than having to enter the username and password in that horrible pop up?

I have a login page **"outside"** the area protected by htaccess / htpasswd, and would like to access a file **"inside"** of my protected by htaccess / htpasswd directory by entering the username and password in my php script, rather than enter in the pop up that appears when i try to access the protected area.

Is there any way to do this using both, php and htaccess?

Comment: You could bypass `htaccess` in the PHP script by reading the file server-side and directly handing it to the user.

Comment: you could just get the file with php, it is not restricted like the browser

Comment: How to do this? I think not ...   "You could bypass htaccess in the PHP script by reading the file server-side and directly handing it to the user. –  merlin2011 5 mins ago"

Comment: `echo(file_get_contents('path/to/file'));`

Comment: @Dagon, I am not sure how well the browser would take it if the file was actually binary and we never told the browser. I have added a sample script as an answer.

Comment: well we don't know the file type so ...

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comment, consider the following `PHP` script, which reads the protected file and gives it to the user if the proper password `foobar` is supplied.

Keep in mind that if your connection is not over `SSL`, you are sending your password in the clear.

```
   <?php

    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $filename = "MyFoo.txt";

    $file = "path/to/protected/directory/$filename";

    if($pass == "foobar")
    {
        header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);
    }
    if(isset($_POST))
    {?>
        <form method="POST" action="">
            Password <input type="password" name="pass"></input>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get File" ></input>
            </form>
    <?}
    ?>
```

Comment: The username and password is in the htpasswd in protected directory.. I need to check this.. Instead the pop up started by the htaccess shows.

Comment: @LincesMarques, When PHP reads the file, it should be a standard filesystem file read, not subject to `.htaccess`. Have you tried this and still gotten the `htaccess` password prompt?